# Получить цифры из строки

Tags: python

Есть следующая строка:

```
a = [[["0,5"], ["0,6"], ["0,7"]]]
```

Количество квадратных скобок в начале и в конце строки может быть разным, чаще всего либо две, либо три скобки.

Как можно получить цифры 0,5; 0,6; 0,7 ?

Спасибо!

Comment: цифры или числа? Кроме того, 0,5 и т.д. не являются int,

Comment: А `Pandas` при чём здесь? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(items, ignore_types=(str, bytes)):
    """
      str, bytes - являются итерируемыми объектами,
       но их хотим возвращать целыми
    """
    for x in items:
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, ignore_types):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

items = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6], 7], 8, ('A', {'B', 'C'})]


for x in flatten(items):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Добавьте ещё что на выходе получается

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно ещё:

```
sp2=[]
a = [[["0,5"], ["0,6"], ["0,7"]]]
for i in a[0]:
    for x in i: sp2.append(float(x.replace(',', '.')))
print(sp2)
```

Что выводится:

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
```